# .NET MAUI ScrollView doesn't scroll in both directions

Tags: .net, scroll, maui

I created below code with ScrollView in .NET MAUI. I want to scroll in vertical and horizontal direction. But it scrolls only horizontally (in Android emulator). Which attributes I've have to add/change?

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Both" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            <Frame BorderColor="Red">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="150">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                   
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </ScrollView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: It will only scroll if the content is larger than the container

Comment: The content is larger than the container. HeightRequest is only 150 and there are 4 lines with large font.

Comment: That is nested several layers below the scroll view.

Comment: I've reduced it to only the grid inside scrollview. But same result. Let me ask a general question: How looks XAML code for a grid with limited size where I can scroll in both directions.

Comment: it's still the same issue.  The Contents of the ScrollView (the Grid) are **not** larger than the scrollview, so there is nothing for it to scroll.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Look at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7811 for further information.

Comment: Indeed there is a bug on Android, but not on Windows. If you test your code on Windows, does it scroll both ways? If not, then as Jason said, you haven't created a ScrollView whose contents are larger than the scrollview. To see correct behavior, put Height/Width Requests on BOTH `ScrollView`, AND its IMMEDIATE CHILD (in your code, `Frame`). If you test on Windows, and H/W of ScrollView are both smaller than H/W of Frame, then you will be able to scroll in both directions. Then to have it work on Android, use workaround (nested ScrollViews, one H, one V) seen in that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a maui project to test your code. First of all, `HeightRequest="150"` is less than the limit of the screen's height. So it should be deleted.

And then I created a xamarin.forms project to run the same code. The scroll view can scroll both vertically and horizontally on the android emulator. So it seems a bug for android in the maui.

You can follow up the issue on the github you mentioned or try the solution in it. I have test it, the stacklayout can be scrolled both vertically and horizontally.

The xaml code:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical"  >
        <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Frame BorderColor="Red">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*" WidthRequest="600" >
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                        <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum." FontSize="Large"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```